# Uploading file from android to server fails

Tags: java, android, http, file-upload, upload

I am trying to upload a file to a server. I have tried to do this in two ways.

**First Method**

Here is the code for the first method:

```
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary = "*****";
int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
File sourceFile = new File(fileName);

try {
    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/test.py?action=upload&code=123");

    // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
    conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName);

    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    // create a buffer of  maximum size
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // read file and write it into form...
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {

        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    }

    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
            + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

    if(serverResponseCode == 200){
    }

    //close the streams //
    fileInputStream.close();
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
} catch (Exception e) {

    Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
            + e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

At the line `int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();` the code throws an exception as below:

```
java.io.EOFException
            at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readHeaders(HttpEngine.java:609)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:562)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:814)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:293)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:505)
            at ir.fajrdev.uploader.HTTP.HTTPUploader.upload1(HTTPUploader.java:241)
            at ir.fajrdev.uploader.HTTP.HTTPUploader.uploadAllFiles(HTTPUploader.java:48)
            at ir.fajrdev.uploader.fragments.UploadFragment$3$1.run(UploadFragment.java:74)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I have searched for this exception and it seems it's a bug but non of the answers worked for me.

**Second Method**

So I tried another method like below:

```
File file = new File(f.address);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/test.py?action=upload&code=123");

try {
    MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    FileBody fb = new FileBody(file);
    entityBuilder.addPart("file", fb);

    HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();

    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    if ("done".equals(result)) {
        DatabaseManager.sharedDB().fileUploaded(f.id);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem here is the response should be `done` but it's a null string. After logging from the server side it says there is no attribute `filename`. The server is working because I could upload files with an iOS app I have written before but I can't this done on an android app too.

I have checked the data being sent in both methods and they seem simular except in the second one there is a line `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` that doesn't exist in the first method output.

Sorry for the long question:)

Comment: You don't seem to be calling connect() in your first method.

Comment: @CPUTerminator I found that code on the net as a working sample. Inspite of that I tried the `connect()` method and the same exception was thrown:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a stupid problem:)

My app runs a NanoHttpd server and I upload files to it. Then I have a button to upload files to a server on the net. The problem is I upload whatever is uploaded to me! (I didn't put the parameters in the code in the question so it would be easier to find the solution). What happens is NanoHttpd creates a parameter named `file` for each file that has been uploaded. So when I upload all of those parameters the server, it sees the `file` parameter but no filename with it. So I just removed the `file` parameter and now the second method works great!

P.S: Still the first method doesn't work (Neither the code in the question nor the code in the answers). Don't now why?!

Answer (score 0):

```
 try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                              +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                              +uploadFileName;

                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                          messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                                   + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this sample code, it will work fine

http://androidexample.com/download_android_example/download.html?view=download&token=fe9fc289c3ff0af142b6d3bead98a923

Comment: The link is not available for me. I should create an account. What is it about?